# How to create an expandeble multible imagebutton viewer in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I want to have multiple images displayed in a row (gridlike) that will expand when the user changes resolution, similar to this: https://youtu.be/-Np8fsrqss0 but without changing offsets via script. Is there ant easy way to do this without manually changing size/pos of all images to fit?

I have already tried to add buttons and assign a row and column based on its id (0-24) but it only auto expands to fill the space: https://youtu.be/I1C-yMywYKY, I have tried to compensate for this by changing the scale and position of all buttons, but only managed to do this: https://youtu.be/-Np8fsrqss0.

```cs
PosterAtScreen = (int)(Application.Current.MainPage.Width / (double)POSTER_WITH);
Grid.SetColumn(imageButtons[i], i % PosterAtScreen);
Grid.SetRow(imageButtons[i], (int)(i/PosterAtScreen));
```

Comment: Are you developing a phone based app? It looks like a webSite or pc app from your video.

Comment: Yep, it is supsed to very simular to IMDb, but for that I need a nice image expander that works on all resolutions. Right now its kinda wack because all the images move and change size sligtly when i change resolution.

Comment: Did you give a fixed height/width to `RowDefinition /ColumnDefinition` of Grid?

Comment: Thanks, it did solve it if I only had the grid to set the row definitions to star and then removing any posters outside the grid. This worked, but I actually found that placing the grid in a stacklayout that is placed in a ScrollView and spawning the buttons with VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start solved all my problems, ` <ScrollView >
        <StackLayout>
            <Grid x:Name="GRID">

            </Grid>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by placing the grid in a stacklayout that is placed in a scrollview, like this:

```
<ScrollView >
    <StackLayout>
        <Grid x:Name="GRID">

        </Grid>
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And then spawning the image buttons with `VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start`, like this:

```
new ImageButton { Source = source, Margin = new Thickness() { Top = 0, Bottom = 0, Left = 0, Right = 0 }, Padding = new Thickness() { Top = 0, Bottom = 0, Left = 0, Right = 0 }, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start };
```

For placing the posters at the right row/column I used

```
GRID.RowSpacing = -POSTER_HIGHT-5;

for (int i = 0; i < imageButtons.Count; i++) {
    try {
        Grid.SetColumn(imageButtons[i], i % PosterAtScreenWith);
        Grid.SetRow(imageButtons[i], (int)(i / PosterAtScreenWith));   
    }
    catch (Exception) {
        throw;
    }
}
```

```
which resulted in: https://vimeo.com/356240684
```